# Will Burdock grow from the root?

Tags: planting

Does Burdock grow from the root of the plant, or do you need to plant a seed to get it to propagate?

Comment: Some more information about your geography and growing conditions would be helpful to include in the question.

Comment: A low swampish area in MN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Burdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium) is a binennial and widely considered a noxious weed. While it does not appear to be on the MN statewide list, there may also be county lists, so check that before planting any.

Year one, it grows from seed and makes leaves and stores energy in the root.

Year two, it makes a tall stalk with highly annoying burrs. Those burrs spread the seed far and wide, which comes back to it being considered noxious.

I would advise against introducing it to an area that does not have it, whether or not it's actually prohibited.

[This page from UMN extension](http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/diagnose/weed/broadleaf/basal/cburdock.html) has a broken link that calls it a "Minnesota Secondary Noxious Weed"